# wrap a general python function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My purpose is to create a custom layer in keras with a weight matrix which has a dimension greater than input (output dimension the same), whereas the extra parameters are used for a function to process (weights %*% inputs). The function is NOT written in tensorflow and it would be quite tedious to do that, so I've tried to use the tensorflow's py_func. However, the NN breaks with "ValueError: None values not supported."

The master code for my own layer is that of Dense with some changes. W is the matrix of weights with dimension [input_dim+n,output_dim]. Assume, there is a general function "func" with n parameters and it should be evaluated on (W %*% Input).

```
def func(self,output):  
      do something
      return something
```

Now we wrap this function in call:

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
      output = K.dot(x, self.W[self.n:,:])
      if self.use_bias:
            output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias)
      if self.activation is not None:
            output = tf.reshape(tf.py_func(self.func,[output],tf.float32),(-1,self.units))
            output = self.activation(output)
      return output
```

The "None" error occurs in self.activation. py_func works flawlessly when using own session, but here seems like this embedding into a Keras layer won't deliver the expected result. It also fails if `func(x)=x*x`.

Comment: You use `inputs` in K.dot in the first line of call. Shouldn't this be `x`?

Comment: And shouldn't `self.output` be `output` in `py_func`?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Generally, the py_func should receive some data and I have a feeling that it doesn't.